# Removing RTP Extensions in GStreamer

Tags: rtp, mpeg, gstreamer-1.0

In a gstreamer (v1.17.0) application coded in C++, I have a stream of MPEG-TS/rtp with a specific-purpose rtp extension. I guess that rtpmp2tdepay has a problem with rtp extensions, as when I bypass the part of the chain adding rtp extensions, everything seems OK. So I decided to remove the rtp extension before rtpmp2tdepay element.
But as there is no remove_extension kind of thing in GstRtpBuffer, I have encountered problems with that.
This is my code, which results in segmentation faults:

```
  GstRTPBuffer rtp = GST_RTP_BUFFER_INIT;  
  GstBuffer *buf = gst_buffer_make_writable(inputbuf);
  gst_rtp_buffer_map(buf, GST_MAP_READWRITE, &rtp);
  gst_rtp_buffer_set_extension(&rtp, 0);
  if ((&rtp)->map[1].memory != NULL)  
  {
    gst_buffer_unmap(buf, &((&rtp)->map[1]));
  }
  gst_rtp_buffer_unmap(&rtp);
  return buf;
```

The error I encouter is this:

```
(receiver:1903): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 13:19:43.409: gst_mini_object_unlock: assertion '(state & access_mode) == access_mode' failed
(receiver:1903): GStreamer-WARNING **: 13:19:43.409: free_priv_data: object finalizing but still has parent (object:0x7f4ea800d000, parent:0x7f4eb0107d80)
```

and later on:

```
(receiver:1903): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 13:19:43.409: gst_mini_object_lock: assertion 'GST_MINI_OBJECT_IS_LOCKABLE (object)' failed
```

What is wrong with this code? Is there a better way to do this?